# Pronunciation: the Erdős–Rado partition notation

Tags: terminology, infinite-combinatorics, notation

The Erdős–Rado notation $a \rightarrow (b)^c_d$ is common in partition calculus / combinatorial set theory, as well as its negation $a \not\rightarrow (b)^c_d$. In that field, is there a standard way to read them out loud?

Comment: I'd read them as "ay arrows bee see dee", but let's wait for someone who actually gave a talk about this recently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Community wiki because it is answered over at [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/674961/how-to-pronounce-the-partition-relation).

[image]

[source](https://books.google.nl/books?id=tCATRdtV_cwC)